# Why does it different beween log() and log(double()) in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I'm shocked about the difference between log and log(double) in matlab.
as I know, log(255) = 2.4065... but my matlab is 5.5413.
How could it difference between them?
Is this bug?

Comment: There is no bug.  The `log()` function in Matlab operates on base e, and you can verify this by opening a calculator and taking e ^ 5.5413 which will give you 255.

Comment: Could you explain the title of your question in the body? Where does `double()` come into it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matlab's [`log`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/log.html) function is base `e` (that's your `5.54...`).  I think you're looking for [`log10`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/log10.html) (that's your `2.40...`).

---

Most programming languages that come to mind (MATLAB, Fortran, C, PHP, Javascript) default to using `log` for the natural logarithm without a base specified.
I'd say, arguably, it is because logarithms involving `e` are much more prevalent than those involving `10` (though they are usually important enough to receive a function of their own).

Comment: You beat me to it by literally 5 seconds ;-(

Comment: and you beat me by 0.5 seconds